# Error in Declaring Arrays in Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a script in which I'm reading a file into an array line by line.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter audio file name. (File must be of .wav format)"

read fileName

echo "Enter path of the audio file"

read path

echo "Enter folder name"

read outputfolder 

mkdir -p $outputfolder

echo "Processing $fileName"
./ilp_diarization2.sh $path/$fileName.wav 120 $outputfolder


#value="$(grep "$fileName.*S" $outputfolder/$fileName/$fileName.g.3.seg)"


#echo "${value}"

awk '{ print $3" "$4}' $outputfolder/$fileName/$fileName.g.3.seg > a

#var=$(awk '{ print $1 }' a) > 2

#echo "${var[0]}


getArray() {
    array=() # Create array
    while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
    do
        array+=("$line") # Append line to the array
    done < "$1"
}

getArray "a" #file name
```

The error I'm having is in the array deceleration.

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

I have tried using

```
array="()"
```

but none of them seems to work.

Here are the content of the file:

```
S0 [
42 4677
S10 [
4719 1266
6020 3618
9667 8463
```

Comment: How are you executing the script? `sh` or `bash`?

Comment: It's a .sh  file.

Comment: Try `./yourfile` to execute your file.

Comment: File name is go2.sh.
I'm executing it by **sudo ./go2.sh** command. It still gives me the error. 
I think the error is in the code and not the command.

Comment: Try to add `#!/bin/bash` to the first line.

Comment: Here you go, found a relevant question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253892/syntax-error-unexpected-when-creating-an-array

Comment: **#!/bin/bash** doesn't seem to make any difference. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I try in my file and it ok: `#!/bin/bash

array=() # Create array
while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
do
  array+=("$line") # Append line to the array
done < "$1"

echo ${!array[@]}` 
 and run with command `bash filename.sh input_file_name`

Comment: What version of bash do you have?  `bash --version`

Comment: @MarounMaroun When I run the script as **sh go2.sh**, it gives me the second error  **cannot create a: Permission denied**. 
But when I run it as bash **./go2.sh**, it gives me only one error mentioned in the post.

Comment: @Saad Try with `sudo`.

Comment: @pikand version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @MarounMaroun not working.

Comment: The filename doesn't matter; in particular, the ".sh" bit is irrelevant.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: @melpomene `./go2.sh: 34: ./go2.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")`

Comment: @Saad What you posted here doesn't have 34 lines. Show your real code.

Comment: That message doesn't look like a bash error. Bash prints things like `./go2.sh: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token \`('`. I suspect you're running your code with dash, not bash.

Comment: @melpomene I have edited my post. Kindly check it and see if there's a mistake anywhere in the script.

Comment: I made a new file .sh file with and copy pasted the script with readarray command as mentioned by Nahuel in the answer. It is now working correctly. I still don't understand what is the issue with the previous file. It has the same code on it as the new one. @melpomene

Comment: @Saad What does `xxd go2.sh | head` report for your original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your version doesn't support arrays, otherwise `readarray` is a bash builtin and does same as function

```
help readarray

readarray -t my_array < filename
```

Comment: I have bash version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). 
Which version should I have to use readarray command?

Comment: your script isn't executing with this shell : add `ps -p $$` inside script, also `echo "${BASH_VERSION}"` should display 4.3.48

Comment: I have edited my post. Kindly go through it again and see if there's any error in the code.

Comment: I made a new file .sh file with and copy pasted the script with readarray command, it is now working correctly. 
I still don't understand what is the issue with the previous file. It has the same code on it as the new one.

Comment: the interpreter may not be what you expect. Have you added the commands `ps -p $$` and `echo "version: ${BASH_VERSION}"`, also can you show the command line to launch the script